# Redirecting to mailto: links, how universally successful?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, mailto, http-redirect

I'm on a 2012 Macbook running 10.7.5 (Lion), and `mailto:` links embedded in HTML work just fine, i.e., they trigger Apple Mail to open a new email.

However, in the backend of web laravel (php) application when I do a `redirect()` to the same `mailto:` link, I don't get Apple Mail or Gmail to open a new email. On the other hand, my other Macbook running 10.11.1 (El Capitan) works just fine with the `redirect()`, again meaning Apple Mail gets triggered.

So I guess this seems like a laravel issue though it could be a OS/app version issue. Therefore my question is how well-supported are redirect mailto links where the expected behavior isn't to a webpage but rather a new email?

Comment: Why not use the network inspector so you can be sure it's a laravel issue?

Comment: @Mr.Llama so dev tools and look for what?

Comment: This might be a browser issue. Are you using the same one on both machines? I'm not familiar with Laravel, so I can only assume it sets the Location-header to mailto. Maybe try a JavaScript redirect.

Comment: Look for an actual `Location: mailto:email@example.com`.  If it's present, it's a browser issue, not a laravel issue.

Comment: How does this "seem like a Laravel issue" if one computer works and one doesn't?

Comment: @ceejayoz good point. You are right, it seems like a computer issue.

Comment: And weirdly enough, now that I opened Apple Mail (I actually didn't have it initiated on the 10.7.5 computer), I'm getting the proper behavior. I guess because many people will have a mail application initiated so maybe this issue is moot.??

Comment: @timpeterson That sounds like the machine didn't have any apps registered to respond to `mailto` schemes until you opened a mail client the first time.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think you're correct. I wonder is that like 1% of computer users today or still a decently high %?

Comment: @ceejayoz you are correct so if you want to create an answer I'll accept it and this question can have an answer.